# Applying Taylor expansion of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, exponential-function

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.02173.pdf), p. 26., Theorem 3.8.

In the proof of this Theorem, it is said that in order to deduce from the statement
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\qquad\mathcal{H}(f^n)\leq (1+2\kappa\delta t)^{-n}\mathcal{H}(f^0)
$$
that, for all $\delta t>0$, there exists $k>0$ (explicit) with $\lim_{\delta t\to 0}k=\kappa$, such that
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\qquad\mathcal{H}(f^n)\leq e^{-2kn\delta t}\mathcal{H}(f^0)
$$

one just needs to do a Taylor development of the exponential function. How is that meant?

---

As far as I see, the role of $\mathcal{H}$ does not play any role for my question (this is why I do not mention its very lengthy definition here).

I do not have an exact idea. But I am pretty sure one needs
$$
1+2\kappa\delta t + O((\delta t)^2)=e^{2\kappa\delta t},\quad\textrm{ as }\delta t\to 0,
$$
where $O(\cdot)$ is the Big-O notation. Thus, if one defines some $k=k(\delta t)=\kappa + \varphi$ with $\varphi=\varphi(\delta t)\to 0$ as $\delta t\to 0$, one should have, as $\delta t\to 0$,
$$
1+2\kappa\delta t = e^{2k\delta t}\tag{1}
$$

I am note sure if this is thought too naively. Particularly, I am not sure if for each fixed $\delta t>0$, equation (1) holds; I think if $\delta t>0$ is small enough, (1) holds if one chooses $\varphi$ appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming all things are positive.

I'm sure that a Taylor argument like yours should work out fine, but you can also just define
$$
k = \frac{\log(1+2\kappa\delta t)}{2\delta t}.
$$
Then $k>0$,
$
e^{2k\delta t} = 1+2\kappa\delta t,
$
and
$
\lim_{\delta t\to0^+} k = \kappa
$.

---

I think to finish your argument, you would just need to define your $\varphi$ such that $e^{2k\delta t} = 1+2\kappa\delta t$ holds, and then show the desired properties from there.

---

I'll add a way to finish your Taylor argument. There are probably slightly sleeker ways than what follows, but here goes.

For simplicity of notation, let $h=2\delta t$. Choose a function $\varphi(h)$ such that
$$ \tag{$\ast$}
e^{(\kappa+\varphi(h))h} = 1+\kappa h.
$$
Can we do this? Yes, just solve the equation to find a valid $\varphi$ (it's similar to how I defined $k$ earlier). Define $k(h) = \kappa + \varphi(h)$.

From $(\ast)$, it follows that $h\to0$ implies $(\kappa+\varphi(h))h\to0$. Then,
$$
1+\kappa h = e^{(\kappa+\varphi(h))h}
= 1 + (\kappa+\varphi(h))h + o_{h\to0}((\kappa+\varphi(h))h),
$$
where I use little-oh notation. From that equation, we get $\varphi(h)h = o((\kappa+\varphi(h))h),$ which implies (use the definition of little oh) that $\varphi(h)=o(1)$, which is what we wanted. Oh, and also $k>0$ for $h>0$ follows from $(\ast)$.

Comment: The thing is that I am not sure if, for given $\delta t >0$, I can choose $\varphi$ such that $e^{2k\delta t}=1+2\kappa\delta t$. I only see this equality for $\delta t\to 0$.

Comment: @selector Take a look at my edit now

Comment: $\varphi(h)h\in o((\kappa+\varphi(h))h)$ means that for any constant $\varepsilon >0$, there exists some $h_0$ such that
$$
\vert\varphi(h)h\rvert\leq\varepsilon ((\kappa+\varphi(h))h)\textrm{ for all }h\leq h_0.
$$
How do you deduce that $\varphi(h)=o(1)$? What I get is that 
$$
\varphi(h)=o(\kappa+\varphi(h))
$$
since $h>0$ and so we can divide by $h$.

Comment: We can write the little oh condition as
$$
\varphi(h)h = \varepsilon(h)(\kappa+\varphi(h))h,
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a function that converges to zero. Solve for $\varphi$ and see that the result goes to zero. (By the way, I recommend working with the "limit definition" of big/little oh - the one that looks at $f/g$ - when possible, i.e. when $g$ is non-zero).

Comment: $\varphi(h)h = o((\kappa+\varphi(h))h)$ as $h\to 0$ means that 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\varphi(h)h}{(\kappa+\varphi(h))h}=0.
$$
Dividing by $h$, this means
$$
\lim_{h\to\infty}\frac{\varphi(h)}{\kappa+\varphi(h)}=0
$$
And now?

Comment: @selector Yes (except your second limit should still be for $h\to0$). That means
$$
\frac{\varphi(h)}{\kappa+\varphi(h)} = \varepsilon(h),
$$
where $\lim\varepsilon(h) = 0$. Rewriting gives
$$
\varphi(h) = \frac{\varepsilon(h)\kappa}{1-\varepsilon(h)}\to0.
$$